# How can i set size of openInfoWindowHtml in google Map

Tags: asp.net, javascript, google-maps

Please help me to change size of openInfoWindowHtml in google map and plez tell me can i make it popup out of map area also..? i mean my map area is very small but i want that when user click on Marker this openInfoWindowHtml should show popup and if its crossing size of map than its should show beyond the boundary of google map. ( i am working in asp.net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways that you can influence the size of the InfoWindow. First, you can pass a GInfoWindowOptions object when you call openInfoWindowHtml (see: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GInfoWindowOptions) Second, you can wrap the contents of the InfoWindow in a div and use CSS to set the size of that div.

Regardless of which method you use to set the size of the InfoWindow, it can never exceed the bounds of the map canvas (area).